# Matlab loading files in listbox error: Extraneous arguments entered

Tags: matlab, listbox

I am new to matlab and I am trying to load multiple files in a list box. By far i have this code but it shows me this mistake:
Extraneous arguments entered, please check the documentation.
This is what I have as code:

```
% --- Executes on button press in load.
function load_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to load (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

[flnm, flpth,cCheck]=uigetfile({'*.mp3'},...
                            'File Select',...
                            'Multiset', 'on');
 %fullpathname=strcat(pathname, filename);
 %text=audioread(fullpathname);
 %set(handles.path_song, 'String',fullpathname);%show full path name in the listbox

 assignin('base','flnm',flnm);
 assignin('base','flpth',flpth);
 assignin('base','cCheck',cCheck);

 %If the user did not press the cancell button
if(cCheck==0)
%Reset selection to first entry
set(handles.playlist,'Value',1);
%Show selected filenames
set(handles.playlist,'String',flnm);
end
%LIST------------------------Display Files---------------------------------

function playlist_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to playlist (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: contents = cellstr(get(hObject,'String')) returns playlist contents    as cell array
%        contents{get(hObject,'Value')} returns selected item from playlist  

listStr=get(hObject,'String');
listVal=get(hObject,'Value');

%Display Selected files
if(iscell(listStr))
   fileName=playlistStr(listVal);
   fprintf('Selected file:%s\n',fileName);
else
   fileName=listStr;
   fprintf('Selected file:%s\n',fileName);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code:

- in the `load_Callback` cllback

  - in the call to `uigetfile` there is a typo: the propery `Multiset` should be `Multiselect`
  - the test `if(cCheck==0)` should be `if(cCheck)`: if the user presses the `Open` pushbutton, `uigetfile` returns `1`
- in the `playlist_Callback`

  - in the `if(iscell(listStr))`

    - the name of the list should be `listStr` instead of `playlistStr`
    - if the condition is met (that is if `listStr` is a `cellarray`) you have to convert the selected item (`listStr(listVal)`) from `cellarray` to a `char` string by using the `char` function because `fprintf` is not defined for `cell` input

Fixing the above errors, the two callback result:

```
% --- Executes on button press in load.
function load_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to load (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% [flnm, flpth,cCheck]=uigetfile({'*.txt'},...
%                             'File Select',...
%                             'Multiset', 'on');
[flnm, flpth,cCheck]=uigetfile({'*.txt'},...
                            'File Select',...
                            'Multiselect', 'on');
%fullpathname=strcat(pathname, filename);
 %text=audioread(fullpathname);
 %set(handles.path_song, 'String',fullpathname);%show full path name in the listbox

assignin('base','flnm',flnm);
assignin('base','flpth',flpth);
assignin('base','cCheck',cCheck);

%If the user did not press the cancell button
%If the user did not press the cancell button
% if(cCheck==0)
if(cCheck)
   %Reset selection to first entry
   set(handles.playlist,'Value',1);
   %Show selected filenames
   set(handles.playlist,'String',flnm);
end

%LIST------------------------Display Files---------------------------------

function playlist_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to playlist (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: contents = cellstr(get(hObject,'String')) returns playlist contents    as cell array
%        contents{get(hObject,'Value')} returns selected item from playlist  

listStr=get(hObject,'String');
listVal=get(hObject,'Value');

%Display Selected files
if(iscell(listStr))
% % %    fileName=playlistStr(listVal);
   fileName=char(listStr(listVal));
   fprintf('Selected file:%s\n',fileName);
else
   fileName=listStr;
   fprintf('Selected file:%s\n',fileName);
end
```

Hope this helps,

Qapla'